# Python - bibliotecas sem a importação "*"

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows

### Como faço para criar uma biblioteca sem ter que importar assim: `from x import *` ou `from x import y`? Somente importando `import x`.

Quem for me responder, por favor pode usar o script abaixo como exemplo de biblioteca.

```
def imprimir():
    print('Olá!')
```

OBS.: quero dar `import nome_da_biblioteca` e não ter que usar `from nome_da_biblioteca import imprimir` ou `from nome_da_biblioteca import *`.

Comment: Como assim biblioteca?

Comment: Uma biblioteca no Python que eu criaria, somente com a função `imprimir()`.

Comment: Você quer adicionar a função imprimir no namespace mas não quer ter que importar a mesma?

Comment: E porque precisa disto?

Comment: Não quero escrever `from biblio import *`, quero escrever somente `import biblio`

Comment: Você pode desde que o arquivo esteja no mesmo diretório.

Comment: Você diz que eu posso fazer `import biblio` só se estiver na mesma pasta, caso contrário: `from biblio import imprimir`, isto?

Comment: @Henrique Exatamente.

Comment: Obrigado, e por que aparece que este post está sem respostas?

Comment: Irei adicionar uma resposta.

Comment: Ah, tudo bem. =D

Comment: Não se esqueça de definir a resposta como correta se a mesma sanou suas dúvidas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ao importar o outro módulo com `import nome_da_biblioteca` ele é executado e o seu espaço de nomes é adicionado ao módulo atual em um objeto do tipo módulo com o mesmo nome do módulo.

Sendo assim, basta usar acesso de atributo para resgatar nomes definidos no módulo importado:

```
import nome_da_biblioteca
nome_da_biblioteca.imprimir()

p = nome_da_biblioteca.imprimir
p()
```

Comment: Obrigado não tinha visto o erro.

Comment: E mesmo assim você me ajudou, Thiago.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode fazer o `import` de um arquivo em `Python` utilizando das seguintes declarações.

```
# foo.py

def foo():
    print("Sou foo")


# bar.py

import foo

def bar():
    print("Executando foo")
    foo.foo()
```

Desde que o mesmo esteja definindo no mesmo diretório posso fazer simplesmente um `import <nome_do_arquivo>` agora pensemos em arquivos definidos em diretórios diferentes, por exemplo, temos um projeto definido da seguinte maneira:

```
project/
    functions/
        __init__.py
        foo.py
    bar.py
```

Se quiséssemos importar o arquivo `foo` estando em `bar` faríamos da seguinte maneira:

```
# foo.py

import functions.foo 

def bar():
    print("Executando foo")
    functions.foo.foo()
```

Isso é só uma explicação abreviada do que se é possível fazer para importar arquivos em `Python` se quiser se aprofundar ainda mais eu indico que estude: ***[Módulos e Pacotes](https://wiki.python.org.br/ModulosPacotes)***.